# Swift TableView conflicts with UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, touch, uipangesturerecognizer

I check all solutions but didn't found and match case for me.
I have **tableView** with cells. Some cell also has **TableView** with Header section and cells.
I used to add UIPanGestureRecognizer to headerSerction to add slide view (delete cell/etc.) For some reasons i couldn't add one more row to implements basic methods.
The issue now, when i scroll main TableView, priority sets to swipe horizontal views inside cells (inner tableView sections contains UIPanGestureRecognizer).
How i can fix that?

**Header sections contains:**

```
func setupGesture(){
    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(wasDragged(_:)))
    gesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    contentsView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    contentsView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    gesture.delegate = self
}
```

**also, drag action:**

```
@objc
func wasDragged(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began || gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.contentsView)
        print(gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX)
        if(gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX < 80) || (gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX > -160){
            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
        }else {
            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 0)
        }

        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: self.contentsView)
    }else{

        if(gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX <= 40) && (gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX >= 0){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
                gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: (self.contentsView.frame.width / 2), y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
            })
        }else if(gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX >= 40) && (gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX >= 0){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
                gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: (self.contentsView.frame.width / 2) + 80, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
            })
        }else if(gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX >= -40) && (gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX <= 0){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
                gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: (self.contentsView.frame.width / 2), y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
            })
        }else if(gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX <= -40) && (gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX >= -80){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
                gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: (self.contentsView.frame.width / 2) - 80, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
            })
        }else if(gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX <= -80) && (gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX >= -120){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
                gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: (self.contentsView.frame.width / 2) - 80, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
            })
        }else if(gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX <= -120) && (gestureRecognizer.view!.frame.minX <= 0){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
                gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: (self.contentsView.frame.width / 2) - 160, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My advice would be "don't do that." It sounds like you're creating an overly complex UI that will be very difficult for your users to control.

Comment: i wish... i have 90% app made by other developer. Now i need to implement this thing. If i add +1 row to tableView to make swipe features for 1st row it will crash all app, because it was made so horrible and i will spend lot of time to fix all.

Comment: From the code and the problem it feels like it would be easier for your to just reimplement the tableView using all the native functionality. Sections, Row edit capabilities and so on. If you can't do that well... You'd probably need an array of gesture recognizers mapped to IndexPaths...

Comment: i implemented array already, but there are conflict when you scroll tableView, sometimes UIPanGestureRecognizer views swipes instead of just scrolling tableView

Comment: if your problem is conflicting gestures, go for `delaysTouchesBegan` on your recognizer.

Comment: You can try to separate logic for pan and scroll gestures using this method of UIGestureRecognizerDelegate.
    
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true 
}

Check for what kind of gesture do you have and try to figure it out.